# UINavigationItem is not deleting from Navigator

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationitem

The UINavigationItem is not deleting from the Navigator. It seems like it's locked on there and the viewcontroller.

[image]

How do I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

You may have previously done embed-in NavigationController without noticing it. So go check that at menu editor.

Moreover, it's better that you unplug all associated navigation controller. So right click your item and see outlet to find if anything connected. If so, remove them all. After all this done, you should be able to remove the item properly.